# How to control line breaks in plain text email views (.text.erb)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, plaintext

Unlike most plain text email related questions, my problem is that there are **too many line breaks** in the plain text emails Rails is sending out.

For simplicity while starting up, I ditched HTML emails altogether and just use plain text emails (using .text.erb views). My problems occur where I have conditional lines in the view, as the new line of code in my view file carries over to the email.

For example:

```
    Line 1
    <%= "Line 2" if false %>
    Line 3
```

will render as:

```
    Line 1

    Line 3
```

and not the intended output:

```
    Line 1
    Line 3
```

My current hack is to use the following:

```
    Line 1
    <%= "Line 2\n" if false %>Line 3
```

This can get really messy when there are multiple conditionals in a row.

Surely there must be a better way!

Answer (score 4):

This is to answer Felix' question on Andy Waite's answer (I don't think multi-line code is possible in comments and this question is *about* multi-line code).

I think `<%= "foo\n" if something -%>` would work, but this seems cleaner to me:

```
Line 1
<% if something -%>
foo
<% end -%>
Line 3
```

Answer (score 3):

If you end the ERB tags with `-%>` that should avoid the extraneous whitespace:

```
<%= "foo" -%>
```

Comment: Would I need to do `<%= "foo\n" if something -%>` if I wanted the new line **if and only if** the text is inserted?

Comment: I think there is a cleaner way to do that, see my answer.